# MSMQ access from mainframe? REST API maybe?

Tags: http, rest, msmq, cobol, mainframe

I need to put and get messages to/from our remote **MSMQ**, but because we will do the **put** s from our mainframe, we need a way that can be implemented in **COBOL**(or PL/1 maybe). My questions are;

1) Is it possible to enable **HTTP GET/POST** requests to put/get messages without WCF implementations? That is, we need to be simply able to make requests as in

```
http://our_server:port/msmq/queue1?operation=put&message=test_message&...
```

2) Is there any other way to access and put messages into **MSMQ** from mainframe?

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I think I couldn' t tell what I want exactly. I have data on mainframe and I want to put these data into a MSMQ which is running on a Windows machine. IBM WebsphereMQ has `WebSphere MQ bridge for HTTP` so that it accepts HTTP requests and puts the requests'  payload into queue. Does MSMQ have such a feature?

Thanks again :)

Comment: Did you ever find a way to retrieve messages from MSMQ using HTTP GET without using WCF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the EZAPI interface programs to manage the traffic natively in your COBOL programs or use one of the many variants of MSMQ to WebsphereMQ or JMS.

The EZAPI stuff will let you do the direct http puts, but you will need to manage it all.

Why not just hook the MSMQ into whatever queueing software you have on the mainframe and make it work the way it was intended?

Answer (score 1):

If your mainframe applications are running in [CICS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r1/index.jsp), then [HTTP client requests](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.internet.doc/topics/dfhtl_outbound.html) are just [API calls](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.applicationprogramming.doc/commands/dfhp4_webconverse.html).  Where I work, we've been doing this in COBOL applications since 2006.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, I think my question was a bit ambiguous. Sorry :) I meant MSMQ is already working on Windows machine and I want it to accept HTTP GET/POST requests. So that I can make requests and put messages into the queue